# How to get current datetime seperated by a dash "-" in JS?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm trying to construct a nice file name. I tried to do it in 1 line in JS, but have not found anything yet. So I did these

```js
const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString().replaceAll('/', '-').replaceAll('_', '-').replaceAll(' ', '-');
const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replaceAll('/', '-').replaceAll('_', '-').replaceAll(' ', '-');
let dateTime = date + '-' + time;
console.log(dateTime);
```

I got

`6-24-2022-3_38_18-PM`

Why is the 2x `_` underscores still there ??

## GOAL

I'm trying to get

`6-24-2022-3-33-17-PM`

Do you guys know a better way to achieve that ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the output. I don't get underscores. You have to replace the colons, too.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the 2x `_` underscores still there ??

You are likely replacing something that isn't actually an underscore

> Do you guys know a better way to achieve that?

Yes. Try using a [RegExp](https://javascript.info/regular-expressions)

```js
const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/[^apm\d]+/gi, '-')
const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace(/[^apm\d]+/gi, '-')
let dateTime = date + '-' + time

console.log(dateTime)
```

This will remove *anything that is **not*** (`[^...]+`) an `a` `p` `m` or **digit** (`\d`).

`/.../gi` are the flags **g**lobal and case-**i**nsensitive.

Comment: A much simper regular expression is `/\W+/g`.

Comment: But that still leaves the underscores

Comment: The underscores are weird. No idea which language uses them, but `/(\W|_)+/g` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString().replaceAll('/', '-').replaceAll('_', '-').replaceAll(' ', '-')
const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replaceAll('/', '-').replaceAll('_', '-').replaceAll(' ', '-')
console.log(date + '-' + time)
```

I see *almost* your desired result: `6-24-2022-3:48:11-PM` (since you did not change `:` (colon) in time.

Comment: I'm ready to delete my demo when it's no longer needed.